# Method returning href to ng-href being called continuously

Tags: angularjs

I have a menu widget in which every menu item can expand into another sub-menu. Something similar to this: http://plnkr.co/MGqCkAFUexSzSfcwthu5?p=preview

The link markup is:

```
<a class="link-class"
    ng-href={{ getLink(item) }}
    ng-style="setTextAlignment(level)">
    {{ item.name }}
 </a>
```

With the following method defined in the controller:

```
 /**
 * @param {!angular.Scope} scope The scope of the directive.
 * @param {!Object} item The menuitem.
 * @return {string} Whether current user can access item.
 * @private
 */
 CollapsibleSubMenu.getLink_ = function(scope, item) {
   console.log('link called');
   return item['subMenu'] ? '' : item['link'];
 };
```

So basically if the item has a submenu (submenu === true), it should not have an href (but the items data from backend has items with submenu: true and a valid link. This was ok for the old implementation of the menu.)

Now the problem is that as soon the menu item appears on screen, I can see the console.log printing messages 'link called' every second or so. The item object once retrieved does not change. So why is this getLink method being called so frequently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses dirty checking instead of using an observable, which means every time the `$digest` loop is executed, your function will be too since it doesn't know if the value has changed or not.

If you want to see this in action, just start typing in the box of the code snippet, and then click the button to see how many times your function has actually been called.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  var numCalls = 0;
  
  $scope.getConstantValue = function(){
    numCalls += 1;
        
    return "Never gonna change";
  };
  
  $scope.getNumberOfCalls = function(){
    $scope.numCalls = numCalls;
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myInput" />
  <p>Number of calls: {{numCalls}}</p>
  <p>{{getConstantValue()}}</p>
  <button type="button" ng-click="getNumberOfCalls()">Update Call Count</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok so does that mean every method on the scope will be called for every digest cycle? If i were to put the method condition directly withing the interpolation directive, something (incorrectly) like:

`ng-href={{ item['subMenu'] && '' || item['link'] }}`

Will this improve the performance?

Comment: If it's a function, then yes... it will get called for every single `$digest` cycle. This is because Angular has to know if the value has changed, and the only way it can do that is to execute the function. If you want to avoid this, then you should instead precompute the results and save them into a variable that can be bound to instead.